# No hot water in kitchen but everywhere else is fine

Tags: water, plumbing-fixture

Discovered issue today after being out of town for 2 days.

When running water from a single handle sink - just cold water when turned to hot setting.

Checked valves below sink.

Cold valve turned off = no water at all.

Hot valves turned off = no normal water temp and pressure.

This is a newer home (10 years)  all PVC piping in the kitchen.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: did you do anything before you left two days ago?

Comment: There is more than 1 hot valve?

Comment: We did nothing new in the last several weeks.

Comment: There is a total of three valves under the sink - one for the cold and hot and one for the central line to shut off the water all at once.

Comment: Is this the only fixture with this problem?

Comment: Di you have a dishwasher? Is it getting hot water?